# How to resolve the upper promise in a chained promise in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have this method in a provider:

```
get() {
    var debugOptionUseLocalDB = 0,
        prodata = [],
        serverAttempts = 0;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.connectionStatus.f() === 'online') {
            return this.getDBfileXHR(this.dbUrl(), serverAttempts)
                .then(function (data) { // success
                    console.log('-normal XHR request succeeded.');
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch((reason)=> {
                    ...
                })
        }
        else{
            ...
        }
    })
}
```

And I am calling it from app.component.ts:

```
           this.updateProDB.get()
                .then( () => {
                    let prodata = this.storageService.get('prodata');
                    this.imagesService.manageStoredImageUrlsNew(prodata);
                })
                .catch((reason)=> {
                    console.error('imagesUrl have not been managed, because updateProDb failed with error:' + reason)
                });
```

I am sure that `this.getDBfileXHR()` resolves because I see '-normal XHR request succeeded.' in the console. However, ̀ this.updateProDB.get()`rejects, and we go to the`.catch()̀`.

Is `resolve(data);` the right way to resolve get() ?

Comment: What is the rejection error?  One option would be to instead of wrapping in a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... })` to instead just directly `return this.getDBfileXHR(this.dbUrl(), serverAttempts)`

Comment: Yes but I need the wrapping, I removed some code here for clarity but there is some logic. 
Actually, I replaced `return this.getDBfileXHR(this.dbUrl(), serverAttempts)
                .then(function (data) { // success` by `return this.getDBfileXHR(this.dbUrl(), serverAttempts)
                .then( (data) => { // success` and its seems to work now....is it weird ?

Comment: The get() resolves with data, but the caller ignores the result.  Is that intentional?  Furthermore, does `this.storageService.get(...` run synchronously?  If not, prodData will be `null` when passed to `manageStoredImageUrl()`  It's good that you've simplified the code for this post, but you may have removed too much.

Comment: Yes storageService runs synchronously. Yes I don't need the result in the caller, so it's intentional, thanks for noting. Indeed, I may have removed too much, but I noticed that with too much code, there is often less help.
So the resolve should be in an arrow function apparently, but how to manage this when you can't use => ?